# Changing button attribute by selecting dropdwon

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have dropdown populating data from dabase, and depend on my dropdown selection i want to change button attribute **(data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal-'value of dropdown'}")**

```
<select id "city">
<option value="12">London</option>
<option value="29">Paris</option>
<option value="35">New York</option>
 ....
<button type="button" data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal-1'}">selected city</button>
```

Comment: `data-uk-modal` > What does this mean ? Are you doing any kind of binding ?

Comment: This is just pop up modal by clicking on button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to do in jQuery.

```
$("#city").on("change", function(e) {
    $("button").data("uk-modal", "{target:'#modal-"+ this.selectedIndex +"'}");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns item number i want to get dropdown values.

Comment: I found it by change `this.selectedIndex` to `$(this).val()`